# Specs2 - Tagging tests to run

Tags: scala, specs2

I have been using ScalaTest for a while and I find pretty useful the ability to Tag your tests and run just those with a specific Tag from the command line.

Is there anything similar in Specs2?

I know that you can run a specific test class with testOnly but I would like to just run a test with a specific Tag within a Specification.

Comment: Try `-Dspecs2.ex="my description"`

Comment: I've just tried the following with no luck: testOnly *GetDataControllerTest -Dspecs2.ex="get the data when receiving a file data source request"

Comment: I copied it from intellij - it show all command when running test. Try with intellij (community is enough for scala)

Comment: Actually I am working with Intellij. How can you tell the IDEA run a specific test? Anyway I would prefer to find out the command line command.

Comment: I click on test definition, then right mouse click - and choose run test

Comment: Thank you for your response but this is not what I am looking for. I know how to run a Specification from Intellij but as I said I need to run a specific tagged test and I want to run this test from the command line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how to do it:

```
import org.specs2.mutable._

class MySpec extends Specification {
  tag("fast")
  "example1" >> ok 

  tag("slow")
  "example2" >> ok 
}
```

Then in sbt

```
sbt> test-only *MySpec* -- include fast
```

You will find more information [here](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.HowTo.html#Tag+examples).